# PHP Expression Woes

Tags: php

I'm trying to do regular expression in PHP but I keep getting bugged. I want it so it's A-Z, 0-9, and the underscore (_) but the underscore cannot be used on the edges of a text. Only on the inside.

Here is waht I have:

```
if (!ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,16}$",$username)) {
// Does not match
}else{
// Good job, within rules!
}
```

Comment: P.S. use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), not `ereg`.

Comment: I hate regular expressions with a passion, it's not your fault. Although if you can get the syntax right they do work well.

Comment: I hate Internet Explorer with a passion but reg expressions are getting there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it should work:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,14}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

I decreased your bounds by `2` because you are accounting for two characters at the beginning/end of the string.

Comment: Place it inside of forward slashes, you need to place regex inside delimiters in php. When it's parsing it it thinks you're using ^ as the first one when really it's part of the expression. Like this: preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,14}[a-zA-Z0-9]$/", $username)

Comment: It compiles fine as a Python regex, so I'm not entirely sure what PHP is complaining about...

Comment: In PHP you need to do that so you can add other things outside that modify it, like case insensitivity. Also, for the record, forwards slash is not the only possible delimiter, it's just the one I prefer.

Comment: The regex is fine, @Blender.  But PHP expects regexes in strings passed to `preg_match` to have extra delimiters around them inside the string; that allows the addition of flags at the end of the regex.  so `'/a/'` matches the first `a`, while `'/a/g` matches all `a`'s.

Answer (score 0):

First, `ereg` is deprecated.  Use `preg_match` instead.

Second, you want to match any strings of letters, digits, and underscores that is at least three characters but no more than 16, as long as it doesn't start or end with an underscore.  @Blender's solution will work.  But once you're using `preg_match`, and therefore PCRE, you have access to features that let you do it a little more compactly: lookaround assertions to handle the leading or trailing underscores, and `\w`, which is predefined for you already as letters, numbers, and underscore:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?!_)\w{3,16}(?<!_)$/', $username)) {
    // Does not match
} else {
    // Good job, within rules!
}
```